# Which special feature does the attack titan have?

Tags: attack-on-titan

As far as I understand, there are 9 different types of Titan Power. One can harden his skin, other can become armored, other is a giant, other can gather other titans, etc. Which special power does the Attack Titan have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we know, immense source of strength and willpower.

Keep in mind that its not only one shifter that can harden their skin. I.e Eren does the same to close the Wall Maria hole.

**Origin**: When the Progenitor Titan (aka Ymir Fritz) died, her soul was split into 9 parts. But this does not mean that each of those parts had only one *special feature*. We have seen all 9 titans and some abilities seem hilarious compared to others (for example "The Jaw" Titan vs "The Beast" Titan.

Thus, maybe each of the 9 shifters has multiple abilities which take a lot of training. But this does not mean that the shifters are different from each other based on one ability.

Comment: I voted you up but willpower? You mean his special feature is "keep trying". What a lame feature lol

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant strength and willpower. That is as far as we can tell. I edited my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A special ability of the Attack Titan has been revealed in the last episode of the anime

> While all of the Nine Titans could receive memories of past inheritors, the Attack Titan could also receive memories of inheritors yet to come

[Attack Titan](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Attack_Titan_(Anime)#Future_memory_inheritance)